# Connect Wired Lan Router to Wi-Fi Signal

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, lan

I have a router that runs a small wired LAN.

Right now this router is connected to an ISP -- also via a wired connection.

I want to have the option of using the ambient Wi Fi, which is often more reliable than the wired ISP connection.  (The Wi Fi and the wired ISP are from two different providers).

What device, or what's the best way, that I can connect the router to the Wi Fi connection?  Perhaps some device that and get the Wi Fi signal and then connect by Ethernet into the router...

Comment: Company/corporate questions are off topic. Super User is for home/personal computer, software and networking questions. You might avoid this being closed if you [edit] your question to exclude the details about your office.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every SoHo WiFi router than can run aftermarket firmware can do this. They generally do this with NAT and bridging, rather than by routing, which makes the solution imperfect but for most typical applications, it works.

If you really want it to be perfect, use an access point and a router. The router can be either wired or wireless. Connect the access point's LAN connection to the router's WAN connection. Configure the access point as a client on the existing WiFi and configure the router normally to provide its own LAN.